# Tomcat Manager: Cannot Upload Large WAR file

Tags: java, apache, amazon-web-services, tomcat8

I am getting an exception while I try to deploy my app using Tomcat manager. The manager fails to upload the file. The size of my war file is 85 MB. But for small war files, the manager works fine. I tried with a "Hello World" application (size 5 KB), and it worked fine.
I have increased max-file-size in manager's web.xml, and also tried increasing connectionTimeout in server.xml. But nothing is helping.

Here is the exception.

```
SEVERE [ajp-nio-8009-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log HTMLManager: FAIL - Deploy Upload Failed, Exception: [org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Proc
essing of multipart/form-data request failed. null]
 java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. null
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2950)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3242)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1136)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:381)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.service(AjpProcessor.java:479)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. null
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:297)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2902)
        ... 29 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.read(AjpProcessor.java:1279)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.readMessage(AjpProcessor.java:618)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.receive(AjpProcessor.java:580)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.refillReadBuffer(AjpProcessor.java:688)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(AjpProcessor.java:1390)
        at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:581)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:343)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.checkByteBufferEof(InputBuffer.java:659)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:183)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:132)
```

Comment: The jar can be dumped properly using unzip or something similar ?

Comment: Yes, I can manually copy the ROOT.war directly to the webapps directory, and it works.

Answer (score 11):

Go to the web.xml of the manager application (/tomcat/webapps/manager/WEB-INF/web.xml).

Increase the max-file-size and max-request-size

```
<multipart-config>
  <!-- 50MB max -->
  <max-file-size>52428800</max-file-size>
  <max-request-size>52428800</max-request-size>
  <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
</multipart-config>
```

Comment: That should work, but what do I do if that file doesn't actually exist? (debian 10, tomcat 9 fresh from apt)

Comment: ... Answer found: It's in `/usr/share/tomcat9-admin/manager/WEB-INF/web.xml`